# How to implement HMAC with JS and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, hmac

I am tying to implement a progressive hmac with PHP and JS.  I think I got the js figured out using crypto.js

```
var hmac = CryptoJS.algo.HMAC.create(CryptoJS.algo.SHA256, "Secret Passphrase");

hmac.update("Message Part 1");
hmac.update("Message Part 2");
hmac.update("Message Part 3");

var hash = hmac.finalize();
```

Taken straight from crypto.js I'm trying to figure out how to duplicate this on the server side with PHP 5.3

Any help on this would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [hash_init()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-init.php), [hash_update()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-update.php) and [hash_final()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-final.php):

```
$ctx = hash_init('sha256', HASH_HMAC, 'Secret Passphrase');
hash_update($ctx, 'Message Part 1');
hash_update($ctx, 'Message Part 2');
hash_update($ctx, 'Message Part 3');
$result = hash_final($ctx);

echo $result;
```